# Как перевести миллисекунды в дни:часы:минуты при помощи Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте. По snmp получаю uptime железки:
    Timeticks: (478549248) 55 days, 9:18:12.48
easysnmp в python получает только мс. То, что в скобках (478549248)
Как привести к такому виду 55 days, 9:18:12.48 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, 478549248 миллисекунд - это примерно 5,5 суток

```
from datetime import timedelta
x = 478549248
d = dtimedelta(milliseconds = x) # 4th argument - milliseconds
print d
>>> 5 days, 12:55:49.248000
```

если посчитать

```
timedelta(x * 10) -->  55 days, 9:18:12.480000
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Работает как надо!

Comment: @Jfs, да Вы правы конечно

Answer (score 2):

У вас единицы не миллисекунды:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta 
>>> timedelta(days=55, hours=9,minutes=18, seconds=12.48)//timedelta(milliseconds=1)
4785492480
```

Ваше число следует на 10 умножить, чтобы миллисекунды получить:

```
>>> str(timedelta(milliseconds=10*478549248))
'55 days, 9:18:12.480000'
```